# Automated website folder backup system needed? Any recommendations?

Tags: web, download, backup-strategies

Hi guys is there any backup software that can take periodic backups of online website folders and store them offline on a local system. Need something robust and would be nice if theres something free that can do the job :)

---

Thanks for the links - I have ftp access and its my website and its a bit of a documents sharing website with user uploads and I would like to maintain a backup of teh files uploaded from time to time on the website on a periodic basis. Just want to automate this process. My local system is windows based though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a website that will be accessed by you from your browser (rather than as the administrator of the site) you should check out [WGet](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). And, if you need to use WGet from a Windows system, checkout [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have shell access at the site, you can use wget:

```
#!/bin/bash
export BCKDIR=`date -u +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"`
wget -m -np -P $BCKDIR http://www.example.com/path/to/dir
```

wget options:

- -m - Mirror everything, follow links
- -np - Don't access parent directories (avoids downloading the whole site)
- -P - Store files below $BCKDIR

If you have shell access, you can use rsync. One way to do it, is to have this loop running in a screen(1) session with automatic login using ssh-agent:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :; do
    export BCKDIR=`date -u +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"`
    rsync -az user@hostname:/path/to/dir $BCKDIR
    sleep 86400 # Sleep 24 hours
done
```

Not sure what OS you're using, but this should run fine under *NIX. And for MS Windows, there's Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the webserver, a cronjob which emails or ftps out the archive would do the job.